# Unable to launch runtime for 'R' script

Tags: sql-server, r

After installing the Advanced Analytics Extensions in SQL Server 2016 (CTP3) the following error appears in SSMS while executing an R-script:

> Unable to launch runtime for 'R' script. Please check the configuration of the 'R' runtime.

What is the remedy?

Comment: Have you checked the configuration of the R runtime, as it suggested?  Please do that and share some information on what you find here.  If you don't know how, the docs should help, but at least clarifying in the question that you aren't sure how to do that would be useful.

Answer (score 3):

Tried different approaches, but only this worked for me:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\R_SERVER\library\RevoScaleR\rxLibs\x64\RegisterRExt" /uninstall
```

Then

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\R_SERVER\library\RevoScaleR\rxLibs\x64\RegisterRExt" /install
```

The approach is similar to the previous answer, but looks like the path to the RegisterRExt.exe was changed in the RTM.

Comment: Path was slightly different for me: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\R_SERVICES\library\RevoScaleR\rxLibs\x64 but close enough that your answer got me there.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are post-install steps which are described in the article ["Post-Installation Server Configuration (SQL Server R Services)"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt590536.aspx).
In particular, executing the following in an elevated CMD did it for me

```
%programfiles%\RRO\RRO-3.2.2-for-RRE-7.5.0\R-3.2.2\library\RevoScaleR\rxLibs\x64\RegisterRExt.exe /install
```

Being CTP3 I think the final docs and setup will be more smooth when released. Currently things are still a bit confusing.