# Can't run R script in SSMS after fresh install

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, ssms

Trying to figure out what went wrong with the install when selecting R Services during the install of SQL Server 2019. I've tried restarting both the SQL service and Launchpad with no results. I also tried increasing the RAM allocation space for the external resources pool to 50% instead of the default 20%. Tried searching around for this error and I can't see anyone who has had the same error except one other [comment on sqlauthority.com](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2016/07/07/sql-server-2016-getting-started-r-services-forecasting-notes-field-131/) that also has no answer.

Trying to run this script just to confirm that R is installed on the server:

```
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script  
  @language = N'R',
  @script = N'OutputDataSet <- InputDataSet',
  @input_data_1 = N'select 1 as hello'
WITH RESULT SETS (([hello] int not null));
GO
```

Produces this error:

```
Msg 39012, Level 16, State 14, Line 16 
Unable to communicate with the runtime for 'R' script for request id: DCF675C1-D581-415C-937E-A4D01E07FFE4. Please check the requirements of 'R' runtime.

STDERR message(s) from external script:  
Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'RevoScaleR', details:   
call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)   
error: fatal error: RevoScaleR cannot be used in this R session anymore, if possible restart R session error code -1066598274, detailed error message might be found in: (standard output unavailable) and (standard error output unavailable) 
Execution halted 
exception while shutting down RxClientPipe: cannot write to BxlServer, child process is dead
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is Bxlserver process running?

Comment: I don't think the BxlServer is a process that runs in the background? I believe that the executable is called from the Launchpad service which in turn is called by the stored procedure sp_execute_external_scripts

Comment: Looking here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/concepts/extension-r?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I actually got it to work. But beware I tried many different fixes and they all did not work until I found what did work for my server situation. Best guide that I found was this blog post by Niels Berglund found [here](https://nielsberglund.com/2018/06/01/sql-server-machine-learning-services-and-sql-server-2017-cu7/). He goes through pretty much everything I went through even though the error we got back was different. Although, once I moved the 'ExtensibilityData' folder I ended up getting the same error as Niels!

However, the **simple solution that seemed to fix my situation was to update SQL Server to CU8**. I tried everything (see below links) but in the end it was because MS put out a release of SQL Server 2019 with a bug in it! I still need to go back and correct all of the folder security mess I created but I think as long as MSSQLLaunchpad has rights to the correct folder and that the R and Python config files are pointing to a "good" folder then it should all work out.

Attempted fixes:

- [moving the folder](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4557/unable-to-communicate-with-the-runtime-for-r-script-in-sql-server/)
- [running the command line unintall/reinstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33473612/unable-to-launch-runtime-for-r-script)
- I wiped out SQL Server and re-installed it again
- [messing with folder security](https://nielsberglund.com/2018/06/01/sql-server-machine-learning-services-and-sql-server-2017-cu7/)